# Variable Naming Convention

Tags: json, reactjs, variables, naming-conventions

I'm working on a Front End system using ReactJS.

I'm following [Airbnb javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables). 
But the API response from the Back End is using JSON with underscored variable names.

This causing inconsistencies in our codes. Are there any good solution for this? Is it common to convert the field names from API response? (i.e the JSON field 'product_id' will be converted to 'productId')

```
const { filter } = this.state;

const filterList = filter.list.map((item, index) => (
  <li
    key={index}
    className={`border-bottom ${item.active ? 'active' : ''}`}
  >
    <a onClick={this.setFilter(item.product_id)}>{item.product_name}</a>
  </li>
));

return (
  <ul className="sort-list grid-container">
    {filterList}
  </ul>
);
```

in the code sample above, we saw variable written in camel case, and underscore. There's not much technical issue. Just the variable naming inconsistencies. I just wondering if this small issue should be tackled or not.

Comment: "causing inconsistencies" isn't a concrete problem to which anyone could offer a solution. What actual issue is it giving you? Show some code and data which causes you a definable problem which someone could post a practical answer to. As for the naming convention question, that's purely a matter of opinion really.

Comment: *Is it common to convert the field names from API response?* - it is. There are case conversion libs but they may be not needed if JSON response doesn't conform front end data structure. Unless back end was designed to take how data is used at front end into account, data structure may differ a lot.